# Execute helper script inside of phar

Tags: php, phar

Is it possible to add a script like a bash script or Python script to a phar and have the phar application execute that script.

A practical example running PHP < 5.4 you cannot join a multicast group using just PHP. So I have PHP exec a Python script that joins the mcast group then I listen using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to extract that file from the `.phar` into a temporary file and execute this file.